# how to just get one file exactly like remote

Tags: git

I know I can do

```
git fetch origin
git --reset origin/master
```

to reset my local to the remote branch. What if I want to solve merge conflicts for some files and for others like x1.cpp , x2.cpp, I just want to keep the remote version (force the remote version) without doing any merge resolution. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Ever heard of branching?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to merge the remote with the local. Only with some files I want to overwrite by local with the remote file without going through merge conflicts resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore a file to its remote version, you can just use:

```
git checkout x1.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which files you always want the remote version of, you can use a custom merge driver for them:

> `git config merge.theirs.driver "mv %B %A"`
>
> `echo x1.cpp merge=theirs >> .git/info/attributes`

and then, just for safety,

> `git checkout`*`upstream/branch`*`-- x1.cpp`

to be sure you're starting out clean.

Note that while this will always take any changed upstream version regardless of what's in the local branch, it won't stop you adding local changes that will then persist until someone merges  a newly-changed version from upstream.